# Negative Lookahead Optional Matching

Tags: regex

I am trying to have a pattern that looks for a certain word, then will match some number of characters following that word, followed by an optional phrase. The optional phrase is in its own capture group, and should not be captured by the some number of characters. My example is as follows:

`(test((.(?!hi)){0,5}))(hi)`

I've tried this and others in various configurations, and given input string of "test hi" this will match "test" on its own, but I cannot get it to match "hi" in the optional capture group.

Edit: 2nd example

`(test((?!tst).{0,5}))(tst)?(hi)`
Running this on "test tst hi" will correctly get 3 groups, however, group 1 will contain "test tst", where it should only contain "test". Groups 2 and 3 are correct in this case.

Comment: can yoou provide some more examples (expected inputs and outputs)?

Comment: @rikyeah I've added a second one though it's not super different.

Comment: I still don t get your question... can you rephrase the whole?

Comment: "match some number of characters" - between how many? Your regex would seem to imply between 0 and 5 (but 0 is not "some number"). It would be better if you include examples of the initial string and what you are expecting to extract from it. Your description of the problem in the first paragraph does not seem to match the examples that follow? And the regex may only be confusing things... why are you capturing the initial word? Why the negative lookahead?

Comment: I have a regex pattern that is looking for specific prefix, and once I find that prefix I want to find whatever {1,10} or so characters that follow it. Except, if I find a certain optional pattern (hi)? in the first case, I want it to stop going up to {1,10} and keep "hi" in the optional group, rather than being captured by the {1,10} group.

Comment: @MrWhite the original pattern was test.{0,5}, which encapsulates the "hi" from the optional group rather than the optional group. The negative lookahead is to try and prevent this behavior, but it causes neither group to match hi.

Answer (score 0):

Your first pattern does not contain a correct tempered greedy token, it should look like

```py
(test)((?:(?!tst).){0,5})(hi)?
#     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/JVgIdJ/3). *Details*:

- `(test)` - Group 1: `test`
- `((?:(?!tst).){0,5})` - Group 2: any one single char, zero to five occurrences, as many as possible, but that does not start a `tst` char sequence
- `(hi)?` - Group 3 (optional): `hi`.

The second regex has got more issues, the worst is that you do not account for whitespaces between `tst` and `hi`. It should be

```
(test)((?:(?!tst).){0,5}?)(?: *(tst))?(?: *(hi))?
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/JVgIdJ/2). *Details*:

- `(test)` - Group 1: `test`
- `((?:(?!tst).){0,5}?)` - Group 2: any one single char, zero to five occurrences, as few as possible, but that does not start a `tst` char sequence
- `(?: *(tst))?` - an optional non-capturing group matching an optional sequence of zero or more spaces and then `tst` captured into Group 3
- `(?: *(hi))?` - an optional non-capturing group matching an optional sequence of zero or more spaces and then `hi` captured into Group 4.